# Array.Copy always row-major?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array

From the MSDN documentation on the [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx) method:

> When copying between multidimensional arrays, the array behaves like a long one-dimensional array, where the rows (or columns) are conceptually laid end to end. For example, if an array has three rows (or columns) with four elements each, copying six elements from the beginning of the array would copy all four elements of the first row (or column) and the first two elements of the second row (or column).

I have always assumed that, in C#, two-dimensional arrays are laid out in [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) (and similarly for higher dimensions), so I'm confused about the meaning of the parenthesized “or columns” in the above documentation. Does it mean that there may be circumstances where the .NET Framework uses column-major ordering?

Comment: That's fairly confusing. Perhaps they are just trying to cover the case where (#rows == 1). I'm pretty sure it's always copied in row-major order. Otherwise, chaos ensues!

Comment: That's what I initially thought as well, but it doesn't hold for the  “three rows (or columns) with four elements each” part. My current guess is that it was worded that way for persons who switch the definitions of rows and columns.

Comment: I think it's trying to be row/column-major agnostic; it doesn't care whether you imagine your first index to mean row or column.

Comment: Not all languages view arrays as row-major. FORTRAN, for example, is column-major. The .NET documentation for `Array.Copy` is necessarily row/column agnostic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I *suspect* it is merely trying to convey that an array **is not a rectangle** - it is a single linear space. Any concept of "row" or "column" is actually the invention of the user. There are no rows and no columns; any convention along the lines of `arr[x,y]` is "row x, column y" or "column x, row y" is purely that: a convention; part of our imagination in conceptualizing something. The only real order is **which index is navigated first**. The first? or the last?

Whether you call that "rows" or "columns" is up to you, and there are examples of both in use in the wild.

Comment: I agree, although the lack of further explanation makes the article more confusing than if they went with the mainstream `[row,column]` convention.

Comment: Also, can you point to any online resource or publication where the first index is called the column? I don't recall coming across that convention.

Comment: @Douglas: There is a FORTRAN for .NET. In FORTRAN, arrays are column-major. So any documentation for that language would call the first index "column."

Comment: @JimMischel: The first index (i.e. the `x` in `array[x,y]`) is still called "row" in Fortran. The language is called "column-major" because _columns_ (i.e. the dimension indexed by `y`) are stored in sequence. Although you raise a valid point about the implications of column-major languages for the `Array.Copy` operation.

Comment: (simplistically) row or column major order is important when iterating over huge arrays (that don't fit into fast memory or cache) using nested loops.  Access a column-major storage with the outer loop over rows (rather than columns) and get many more page faults, cache misses, disk thrashes. Instead of accessing items in sequence from the linear array, you have a stride equal to the column length (number rows) that does not benefit from cache loads that get blocks of linear memory shorter than column length. With tiled memory it is more complex to write your own fast nested loops.