# Get "corners" of a 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensionial array of nullable integers. I wanna get the non-nullable corners of that array - so like, the corners of the array below would be `13, 76, 39, 87`.

```csharp
int?[,] array = new int?[3,9]
{
    { null ,   13 , 21   , null , null ,   52 ,   69 , 76 , null },
    {    9 ,   15 , null ,   36 ,   45 , null , null , 77 , null },
    { null , null , null ,   39 ,   48 ,   53 , null , 79 ,   87 },
};
```

Comment: Do you expect {{13, 76}, {39,87}} back?

Comment: You can get the upper dimensions overall from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260207/how-do-you-get-the-width-and-height-of-a-multi-dimensional-array) but you'll need to iterate through to find your results. Note that your question title doesn't describe what you're doing with any clarity: you are not looking for the corners. The word "corner" evokes the idea of 0,0 0,8 2,0 2,8, which isn't what you're asking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a complete row or column from 2D array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427527/) and [How to get index using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471588/) and [Find index of a value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764970/) and [c# Array.FindAllIndexOf which FindAll IndexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443461/) and [Get the first and last item of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387396/)

Comment: Down-voters who might be thinking this is easy please note _"[an array **is not a rectangle** - it is a single linear space. Any concept of 'row' or 'column' is actually the invention of the user. There are no rows and no columns; any convention along the lines of ... is 'row x, column y' or 'column x, row y' is purely that: a convention; part of our imagination in conceptualizing something. The only real order is **which index is navigated first**. The first? or the last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025551/array-copy-always-row-major)"_ , Marc Gravell, June 2013.

Comment: @Hayden exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From that, I want to get both the first and last non-null elements from the first and last rows each.

2D arrays are a pain in the ass, but they behave like one long array if you iterate them

```
var w = array.GetLength(1);
var h = array.GetLength(0);
var a = array.Cast<int?>();

var ff = a.First(e => e.HasValue);
var fl = a.Take(w).Last(e => e.HasValue);
var lf = a.Skip((h-1)*w).First(e => e.HasValue);
var ll = a.Last(e => e.HasValue);
```

Width is 9, Height is 3, Casting turns it into an enumerable of `int?` which means your corners are the first non null, the last non null in the initial 9, the first non null after skipping 18 and the last non null

Comment: _"2D arrays are a pain in the ass"_ - lol.  Yes I was surprised C# wasn't _row-major_ at least.